# What is the difference between getWidth and getBackBufferWidth in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

In regards to `gdx.graphics`, what is the difference between using `getWidth` and `getHeight`, and using `getBackBufferWidth` and `getBackBufferHeight`?

---

I am learning LibGDX and Java. I programmed formerly in pygame.
To my knowledge, `getBackBuffer` means the width and height of the actual window. Is that true?

Comment: The backbuffer doesn't have to be the same size as the window (although it typically is).  Disclaimer: I don't know LibGDX; this statement comes from my knowledge of Direct3D where this is the case, hence a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getHeight--) explains it. `getWidth` and `getHeight` return the size of the *client area* (this is generally the usable portion of your game window). `getBackBufferWidth` and `getBackBufferHeight` return the size of the *frame buffer*, where actual drawing happens before it's presented to the window.

Sometimes these values differ; for example you might render to frame buffer that is smaller than the window and let presentation to the window upsample it, to achieve a "pixelated" effect. Similarly you might use a larger frame buffer and let it downsample to achieve a crude anti-aliasing effect.

You can look at the source to verify this; note that the specifics of the behavior of the functions differ based on which backend ends up being used. For example, compare [this implementation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9ec39fd23fc3b536624945eef03c24c56a3f1da3/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl3/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3Graphics.java#L146) with [this one](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9763e5ce6cd4bb5ce9a533f1fa449353cebe0dfb/backends/gdx-backend-moe/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosmoe/IOSGraphics.java#L279).

Comment: I would generally advice to only refer to the backbuffer when the need to know size exists. Calculating or reacting to backbuffer size will never lead to errors, only to pixelated or wrongly scaled content but never out of bounds as could happen with GetWidth/Height.